# Changing Cassandra partitioner type

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, nosql

Question about changing partitioner types: i want to use sstableloader to copy data from an old cluster to a newer cluster. but the old cluster is using RandomPartitioner, whereas the new one uses Murmur3Partitioner. You might ask why not using COPY command to export data to csv and import it again? Well we have huge data sets and COPY command would not work (all other node's data would aggregate to one machine).

is it possible to switch new cluster partitioner to RandomPartitioner, do data replication using sstableloader, and switch back? (i tried switching, but cassandra won't restart because of it...)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't change the partitioner. That would require Cassandra to redistribute all the data and is not supported.

You could use sstable2json (with the old yaml) and then json2sstable (with the new yaml) to convert your SSTables manually. Then you can use sstableloader.