# Cassandra data Migration from 1.2 to 3.0.2

Tags: cassandra, migration, etl, data-migration, cassandra-3.0

I know similar questions have been asked before but I think my use case is very specific for which I could not find any answer.

In Production we are using Cassandra 1.2 with ByteOrderPartitioner in a 6 Node cluster with Priam as seed management tool. We have recently upgraded all the dependencies and trying to migrate to Cassandra 3.0.2 with Murmur Partitioner and for backward compatibility we need to enable thrift on new cluster .Also we want to migrate away from Priam also.
I was able to setup new cluster but facing lot of issues during data migration. I tried 3 things:

1) Use Copy Command : Fails when number of rows is large

2) SSTable2Json : Cassandra 3.0.2 has stopped supporting SSTable2Json

3) SSTableloader: Failing I think because of different cassandra version of source and destination

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve endpoint ranges: 
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:233)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:119)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:67)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured table schema_columnfamilies)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:37849)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1562)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1547)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:225)
    ... 2 more

Right now I am kind of stuck,any help regarding this will be deeply appreciated. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

No, You cannot upgrade your sstables **from 1.2 to 3.0.2 directly** since the sstable will differ for different version. This [**link**](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/NEWS.txt) describes the steps for upgrading the cassandra versions. But it also **does not helps for you**, since you are having a change in the partitioner type.

> Changing the partitioner type is not yet supported in cassandra as of
>   now [**(Link)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965834/changing-cassandra-partitioner-type).

One of the solution I would prefer is,

> Create a stand alone utility which is of cassandra 3.0.2 version to read all the data from you source cassandra and write to sstable
>   with the help of [**CQLSSTableWriter**](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated) with the partition type of Murmur Partitioner (The trick is, you are writing
>   the sstable with the version 3.0.2, so this sstable will be easily
>   recognized by your new cluster). Then use SSTableLoader in your target cluster

---

But I am not sure about why you still require backward compatibility, while creating CQLSSTableWritter you can specify the column family schema with keyword 
**"WITH COMPACT STORAGE"**. But I didn't tried CQLSSTableWritter with "WITH COMPACT STORAGE", but without "WITH COMPACT STORAGE" I had tried, it will work for your case too.

Comment: Thanks Jaya,I am still exploring two options:
1) Use CQLSSTableWriter
2) Create schema in new cluster,write java code which is copying data from one cluster to another directly.
As the data is not huge(around 100GB), I am more inclined towards the second option as I am already familiar with code which is writing data in cassandra. Any thoughts on that.

Comment: In my point of view, 2nd option would take much more time when we compared to 1st one. And one more precaution step is to make the writing process with retry logic. Since if any writes get fails with any exception then you need to start the writing process from the first one.

Comment: And one more point for your 2nd option is, I am not sure whether the cassandra will process all your data of 100GB without fail. Since writing of 100 GB in a stretch shot, may give any trouble. From the cassandra documentation, it has to process all of your 100GB data without fail. Not yet tried, but almost you are giving a stress test to cassandra. But you wont fall into any trap if you go with 1st option. Get back the results once done if possible, which might helps me in future.

Comment: Thanks Jaya for suggesting your concerns. Surely I will share the results and some sample code. One of the reason favoring 2nd option is our legacy code. We are using a lot of annotated composite serializer both for keys and columns. If I use CQLSSTableWriter, I will have to manually serialize my column names into blobs for CQL which is again extra work. The approach I am thinking is to do it CF wise to avoid overload,implement retry logic and also keep mutation batch small. I am doing lot of testing before going to prod and if it still fails,I will have to go to option 1

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you try to migrate directly from 1.2 to 3.0.2, you're really looking for trouble.

The migration path should be

1. latest minor or 1.2
2. 2.0 latest minor
3. 2.1 latest minor
4. 3.0.2

For each jump between version, read the https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/NEWS.txt file to know if you need special actions (upgrade sstable, ...)

Comment: Thanks @doanduyhai but this wont work,as if I just upgrade the current version,I will still have to use ByteOrderPartitioner

Comment: Once you choose a partitioner (ByteOrderPartitioner) you'll have to keep it forever. The only way to change partitioner is to create a new cluster and copy all your data to this new cluster using Spark for example

Comment: Sorry for not being clear,but  in my question I have mentioned that I have created a new cluster with new partitioner and now only thing pending is copying data